# Google Maps pin markers hiding and showing but not in the correct way. Any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I set up a js fiddle (but I've never used jsfiddle on my own so it's not working properly to load the map. I'll link it but can't get the map to show) https://jsfiddle.net/96bpp6sw/2/

My issue is with the 3 buttons that hide/show the map pins. The behavior is incorrect. If all checkboxes are selected, all pins are selected. If checkbox "cloud" is the only checkbox checked, then that should be the only selection on the screen and so on and so forth...

Little more info...in the array, index 6 is the category that is associated with the button clicks "cloud, rain, water."

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen">



     </head>
    <body>      
      <div id="map"></div>
        <div class="category">
            <div id="floating-panel">
                <input type="checkbox" value="clouds" checked onclick="filterMarkers(this.value);" id="cat1"><span class="checkbox-text">Clouds</span>
                <input type="checkbox" value="rain" checked  onclick="filterMarkers(this.value);" id="cat2"><span class="checkbox-text">Rain</span>
                <input type="checkbox" value="water" checked onclick="filterMarkers(this.value);" id="cat3"><span class="checkbox-text">Water</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="location-background">
            <form class="form-wrapper cf">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." required>
                <button type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
            </div>
            <div class="scroll-box">
                <table class="list">
                    <tr class="scranton">
                        <th><img class="img-padding" src="images/pin-rain.png" alt ="pin image"></th>
                        <th><p class="align-left">The EFC, with funding from the National Fish and Wildlife Foundation (NFWF), helped to enhance the City...</p></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><img class="img-padding" src="images/pin-cloud.png" alt ="pin image"></th>
                        <th><p class="align-left">With support from the National Fish and Wildlife Foundation (NFWF),the EFC worked with a team led by the Alliance for...</p></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><img class="img-padding" src="images/pin-waves.png" alt ="pin image"></th>
                        <th><p class="align-left">Through funding from the National Fish & Wildlife Foundation (NFWF), the EFC worked with six municipalities located in Lancaster... </p></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><img class="img-padding" src="images/pin-waves.png" alt ="pin image"></th>
                        <th><p class="align-left">In 2012, Warrington Township, Pennsylvania passed a voter approved referendum committing $3 million to open space protection...</p></th>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the js...

```
var m = [];
var filterMarkers;

function initMap() {
    var locations = [
        [
        "Blair County, PA", 40.453132, -78.384223, 
        "With support from the National Fish and Wildlife Foundation (NFWF)" + 
        "report.",
        '<p><b>Resources</b>: <a href="https://efc.umd.edu/assets/sw_case_studies/blair_county_final.pdf" <span>Case Study Blair County, PA</span> </a></p>',
        'images/pin-rain.png',
        'rain'
        ],

        ["Scranton, PA", 41.408969, -75.662412, 
        "The EFC, with funding from the National Fish and Wildlife" + 
        "report.",
        '<p><b>Resources</b>: <a href="https://efc.umd.edu/assets/sw_case_studies/scranton_final.pdf" <span> Case Study Scranton, PA</p>',
        'images/pin-cloud.png',
        'clouds'
        ],

        ["Warrington Township, PA", 40.250319, -75.166212, 
        "In 2012, Warrington Township, Pennsylvania passed a voter approved" +
        "report.",
        '<p><b>Resources</b>: <a href="https://efc.umd.edu/assets/sw_case_studies/warrington_final.pdf" <span> Case Study Warrington Township, PA</p>',
        'images/pin-waves.png',
        'water'
        ]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.488560, -78.065193)
}); 
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;


    for(i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var category = locations[i][6];
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            icon: locations[i][5],
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            category: category,
            map: map    
        }); 

        m.push(marker);
        // ================= code in question =================
        filterMarkers = function (category) {
            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                marker = m[i];
                if (marker.category === category) {
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
                else {
                    marker.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        }

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            var ContentString =
            '<div id="content">' +
            '<div id="siteNotice">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + locations[i][0] + '</h1>' +
            '<div id="bodyContent">' +
            "<p>" + locations[i][3] + "</p>" +
            "<p>" + locations[i][4] + "</p>" +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(ContentString);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
        infowindow.close();
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move filterMarkers inside your 
`$(document).ready` 
function and pass `this` as your parameter for the function

also, check if the checkbox is checked before setting the marker to visible true or false

here is a fiddle to help you to understand it

https://jsfiddle.net/96bpp6sw/8/

***UPDATE***

I have used some weird images for pushpin, you can ignore those

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that's what I'm looking for. Doesn't seem to have all pins on the map when all boxes are checked.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle, please have a look and since the image for rain does not have transparency, you can uncheck it to see the other 2 pins

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured it out a different way. I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

I made a solution instead of the checkboxes I'm using a drop down menu and here is the code that needs edited.

```
<div id="floating-panel">
<select id="type" onchange="filterMarkers(this.value);">
    <option value="all">Select All</option>
    <option value="clouds">clouds</option>
    <option value="rain">rain</option>
    <option value="water">water</option>
</select>
</div>
```

and the js change

```
filterMarkers = function (selectCategory) {
            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                marker = m[i];
                if (marker.category === selectCategory || selectCategory === "all") {
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
                else {
                    marker.setVisible(false);
                } 
            }
        }
```